# Importing VLC Python 2.7.15 On Macbook air

Tags: python-2.7, vlc

I had the same problem on macbook pro, the solutions was to write the command 'brew cask install vlc', and the I could import the vlc.

But now when I try to do the same thing on macbook air it dose not work although the vlc "app" is installed.

this is the Erorr that I am getting: import vlc
ImportError: No module named vlc

> > >

I hope that some one could help me to find a solution for the macbook air.
Thanks in advance !
ZZaim

Answer (score 1):

do you have the vlc-python module installed? If you did not install it, execute the following command in the console to install the vlc-python module

```
pip install vlc-python
```

Comment: Hey, you can not excute this command in the terminal. I used home brew but ir dose not work...

Comment: You can download it at https://github.com/oaubert/python-vlc/tree/master/generated this page corresponding vlc.py files, put it in the script's directory, or on the python installation directory\lib\site - packages directory, then the script head import vlc